# MongoDb shell simple find(): Why not authorized?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-shell

How is this even possible? What am I missing?...

[image: Non-sense query denial]

**Edit 1:**
Ignore the db.post**s**.find vs. db.post.find typo above. I re-auth'd and tried the latter and get exact same denial.

Am I dumb or do MongoDb permissions make no sense at all? Ok don't answer that first part ;-)

Thanks a lot for any advice, I'm stuck on this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You grant only roles to the db `admin`. Not on `d6games-site`.

Try using:

```
db.grantRolesToUser(
  "webuser",
  [
    { role: "readWrite", db: "d6games-site" } ,
  ]
)
```

and very probably:

```
db.revokeRolesFromUser(
    "webuser",
    [
      { role: "readWrite", db: "admin" }
    ]
)
```

Comment: Ok I think this finally gets me sorted out...

The trick is, in Mongo shell, *always* do "use admin" before creating and/or granting/revoking *permissions to any user in **any db***. In the JSON "db" attrib, specify the actual db you want to give this user permission in. 

@Sylvain: Do I understand it now? :-)

Comment: @Locohost Correct. You need the [userAdmin](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#userAdmin) role to grant/revoke permissions. To check the current user's permission, you may use `db.runCommand({connectionStatus : 1})`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your table is 'post' and in query you use 'posts'. Try `db.post.find()`

Comment: No I saw that typo immediately and retried using db.post. See the Edit 1 in OP. Thank you though. I appreciate the reply.